# I want to decompress the .ab file backed up by adb and write it into a tar package

Tags: go, adb, tar

I handle it in the following way

```
bf, err := os.Open(backupFilePath)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("os.Open: ", err)
    return
}
defer bf.Close()
rd := bufio.NewReader(bf)

tarFile, err := os.Create(tarFilePath)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("os.Create: ", err)
    return
}
defer tarFile.Close()

zf, zerr := zlib.NewReader(rd)
if zerr != nil {
    return "", zerr
}
_, err = io.Copy(tarFile, zf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("io.Copy backup.ab -> backup.ab.tar failed:  ", err)
}
zf.Close()
```

An error occurred: io.Copy backup.ab -> backup.ab.tar failed: Unexpected EOF

Is this the case because the .ab file is corrupted or is this the wrong way to handle it?

Comment: Are you sure the backup is not encrypted (no backup password set? What happens if you try to extract the tar file using https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor

Comment: After I use abe.jar to decompress, the file can be opened normally, and the .ab file is unencrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that the .ab file is corrupted.

But there is an issue in your code too. You should skip the first 24 bytes when reading from the .ab file. Otherwise, you should see this error: `zlib: invalid header`. Since you see something else, I would assume that your .ab file is corrupted.

BTW, `rd := bufio.NewReader(bf)` is not needed.

Here is the demo that works for me:

```golang
package main

import (
    "compress/zlib"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    bf, err := os.Open("temp.ab")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer bf.Close()
    if _, err := bf.Seek(24, 0); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    zf, err := zlib.NewReader(bf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer zf.Close()

    tarFile, err := os.Create("temp.tar")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer tarFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(tarFile, zf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

Tested the demo with [backup.ab](https://github.com/manguanghui/File/blob/main/backup.ab), no error was reported. But the generated tar file is invalid:

```
$ tar tvf backup.tar
<...list of files truncated...>
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Tried with `zlib-flate`, got the same result:

```
$ dd if=backup.ab ibs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress > backup2.tar
$ md5sum backup*.tar
3eff01578dec035367688e03b6ec7a72  backup2.tar
3eff01578dec035367688e03b6ec7a72  backup.tar
```

Tried with https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor, got the same result too. So the `backup.ab` file should be corrupted.

```
$ java -jar ~/Downloads/abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup3.tar
$ md5sum backup*.tar
3eff01578dec035367688e03b6ec7a72  backup2.tar
3eff01578dec035367688e03b6ec7a72  backup3.tar
3eff01578dec035367688e03b6ec7a72  backup.tar
```

Comment: I used https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor to extract the .ab file and found that it can be opened normally.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you share the .ab file?

Comment: I put the .ab file on my GitHub.
https://github.com/manguanghui/File/blob/main/backup.ab

Comment: The tar file generated from "backup.ab" is invalid. But `zlib-flate` gives the same result. See my updated answer.

Comment: That is to say, this .ab file should be a damaged file.

Comment: According to https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html by the author of `android-backup-extractor`, it seems that Java's Deflater is special and there is not compatible implementation in other language.

Comment: Just tested with https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor, got the same result too. So it seems that the "backup.ab" file is corrupted. See the updated answer.